# New-ServiceFabricApplication : Application type and version not found

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, azure-service-fabric

I have Visual Studio 2017 and I about to start working with Azure-Service-Fabric (C#).

Just created an Azure Service Fabric application, with stateless service and try to run it. Empty project. No changes on the code-template.

I'm getting this message on the output window:

```
Creating application...
New-ServiceFabricApplication : Application type and version not found
At C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Service 
Fabric\Tools\PSModule\ServiceFabricSDK\Publish-NewServiceFabricApplication.ps1:358 char:9
+         New-ServiceFabricApplication -ApplicationName $ApplicationNam ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Microsoft.Servi...usterConnection:ClusterConnection) [New-ServiceFabr 
   icApplication], FabricElementNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CreateApplicationInstanceErrorId,Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Powershell.NewApplication

Finished executing script 'Publish-NewServiceFabricApplication'.
Time elapsed: 00:00:07.4935602
```

The projects build is passed successfully. Starting to run and then stopped. No other indication to problem except the output window.

What I missing? How to fix?

Comment: Are you sure this is all the error message you see? I think there are more messages before this error occurs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found the problem.

Just change the Azure-Service-Project configuration from "Any CPU" to "x64". Now it's working!

(Don't forget to run it in "Administrator" mode)

Comment: Where to change this?

Comment: Run configuration in Visual Studio.

Comment: Thanks! I get this error when I try to deploy cluster code through Powershell command(_New-ServiceFabricApplication -ApplicationName_). The deployment through Visual Studio is successful though! Any idea how to resolve this even on Powershell?(I am running my powershell in admin mode)

Answer (score 2):

`Publish-NewServiceFabricApplication.ps1` script takes the application type and version from the `ApplicationManifest.xml` of your service fabric application. Please check if you have this file and if the second line has `ApplicationTypeVersion` and `ApplicationTypeName` specified. It should look similar to this:

`<ApplicationManifest xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" ApplicationTypeName="MyAppType" ApplicationTypeVersion="1.0.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2011/01/fabric">`

Comment: Version matched the expected. It's not the problem.